# Ajax call is working only once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a website in which I need to make a ajax call. 
but the problem is that, ajax call is working only once.
 Once it complete one call then there is no effect of clicking button which triggers that call

my java script is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit1222").on('click', function () {

        var name = $("#name1222").val();
        var dataString = 'filter=' + name;
        if (name == '') {
            document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML = "Please Fill All Fields";
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo $action; ?>',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = result;

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and html is

```
<input type='text' id='name1222'>
<input type="submit" id="submit1222">
```

please tell me where i am making mistake.

Comment: Are you replacing the original form with a new form? In that case you may need to rebind the event...

Comment: check your console for errors..?

Comment: Any console errors ? Also,did you check if the response is getting cached ?

Comment: Do add console before the call $.ajax and try to figure out if all data are available.

Comment: can you please post your full HTML code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: What does "there is no effect of clicking button which triggers that call" mean? Why should an AJAX call click your button?

Comment: Full html is needed, especially what is the element 'container'.